# how to check for user defined tables in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

apart from checking if table already exists, how can we verify if it is current user-defined table in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl1()
```

how can we verify it was created by current user if already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like This

```
 SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM pg_tables t where tableowner=current_user 
and tablename='Tablename'  and schemaname='schemaneme'

if cnt = 0 then (CREATE Table TableName)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it works with pg_tales and current_user. Can we use it for multiple tables, if we have hundred tables in one script by having table list or we have to wrap every table with it?

Comment: give the table name in where clause Use In get the tables name and below check the condition using for loop

Comment: sorry i could not get you, could you explain again?

Comment: `tablename='Tablename'  change to `tablename in (tablenames)`. `count(*)` Change to tablename into  rec. Rec as record. now use for loop for create table